# assigning object to button.tag

Tags: vb.net, button, handles

I created a Sub I want to run everytime one of two buttons is clicked. I added the handles of both buttons to the sub so that clicking either one will fire the subroutine.

I placed listview object A in buttonA.tag, and listview object B in buttonB.

When the button is clicked I do my best to extract the listview instance tucked into the button's tag. The problem is there is no instance in the tag. It is simply "nothing."

```
Private Sub Execute(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnA.Click, btnB.Click

        Dim buttonSender As Button = Nothing

        buttonSender = CType(sender, Button)

        Dim btnListView As ListView = buttonSender.Tag

    End Sub
```

-------------------**Edit-1**

```
Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.btnA.Tag = Me.lvA
        Me.btnB.Tag = Me.lvB
    End Sub
```

Your time is appreciated.

Comment: Tried it here, works.  You can't be assigning the listview to the tag correctly?

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part...I actually have an up and a down arrow for A and B so A1 and A2, B1 and B2 I assigned listA to A1 and listB to A2 not as it should be A1 to lvA and B1 to lvB. So if anyone understands that I hope this code is instead a tutorial assigning objects to button.tag... thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
Dim buttonSender As Button = CType(sender, Button)
```

Comment: Negative on that. Buttonsender.tag still registers as nothing... Im wondering if its because the sender is declared an object and it loses the tag property which only pertains to the button class, even though the base class of a button is an object...

Comment: I think Im going to have to use the sender as a pointer to the button object on the form... Then get the tag from the actual button on the from and go from there.